# How do I update data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting blur to update data with multiple `option_id` @ `option_name`  in same time.

Current db

```
option_id   option_name        option_content           option_status
1           web_url            http://localhost.com     1
2           web_name           My Website               1
3           web_description    Welcome to my website    1
4           web_keywords       movies, power, ranger    1
```

php update data

```
$web_name    = $_POST['web_name'];
$web_url     = $_POST['web_url'];
$web_desc    = $_POST['web_desc'];
$web_keyword = $_POST['web_keyword'];
```

**Update From [DR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302453/how-do-i-update-data-to-mysql/4302488#4302488) anwser**

```
$query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
      '{$db->string_escape($web_name, true)}'
      WHERE option_name = 'web_name'";
$db->rq($query);

$query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
     '{$db->string_escape($web_url, true)}'
      WHERE option_name = 'web_url'";
$db->rq($query);

$query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
     '{$db->string_escape($web_desc, true)}'
      WHERE option_name = 'web_desc'";
$db->rq($query);

$query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
     '{$db->string_escape($web_keyword, true)}'
      WHERE option_name = 'web_keyword'";
$db->rq($query);
```

There have a way to make this update queries more simple?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to update with what?

Comment: look like wrong query on my question lol.. DR was give a clue. but I want in short query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use multiple queries:

```
$query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
          '{$db->string_escape($web_name, true)}'
          WHERE option_name = 'web_name'";
$db->rq($query);

$query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
         '{$db->string_escape($web_url, true)}'
          WHERE option_name = 'web_url'";
$db->rq($query);

// And so on...
```

A slightly better approach is to use an associative array:

```
$data['web_name'] = $_POST['web_name'];
$data['web_url'] = $_POST['web_url'];
//and so on...
//Resist the temptation to use $_POST directly!

foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
    $query = "UPDATE web_options SET option_content=
             '{$db->string_escape($value, true)}'
              WHERE option_name = '$name'";
    $db->rq($query);
}
```

Comment: Looks like I need repeat it 20 times if have 20 inputs. Any short query?

Comment: What you have is essentially a list of name-value pairs. You could put them in an array and then loop over that array to update the database. That way at least the database part of your code gets slimmed down.

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE` queries take exactly the same `WHERE` conditions as normal queries.

```
UPDATE `web_options` SET ... WHERE `option_content` = 'My Website';
```

updates all rows where the `option_content` field equals "My Website".

Comment: Every line in this answer starts with the word "update". Do I get an anti-poetry badge or something?

Comment: If only! I think we should petition Joel for one :)

Comment: Rain fell / Thunder rolled / Are you too a poet, now, you donkey son of a donkey? (Turkish saying.)

Comment: @blur In case it wasn't clear: To apply updates to multiple rows at once, use a `WHERE` condition that matches all the rows you want to update. Worst case that means `WHERE option_content = 'My Website' OR option_content = 'Foobar' OR ...`.

Comment: @aib Now that's a novel swear, I have to try to use that sometime. :o) *YOU... donkey son of a donkey!!*

Comment: It's very mild and often humorous, sometimes even used by parents who're telling their children off (which makes it even funnier)

Answer (score 0):

Your table doesn't seem to have columns named `web_name`, `web_url`, `web_desc` or `web_keyword`. I suggest you review your basic SQL tutorial. A lot more carefully this time.

As for the solution... Ah, @deceze just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

in order to use update  , you should know what is option_id you want to target

the option_id must be primary key

and your code will be like this

```
$web_name    = $_POST['shop_name'];
$web_url     = $_POST['shop_url'];
$web_desc    = $_POST['shop_desc'];
$web_keyword = $_POST['shop_keyword'];
$option_id = $_POST['option_id'];

$query = 'UPDATE web_options SET 
        web_name="' . $db->string_escape($web_name, true) . '",
        web_url="' . $db->string_escape($web_url, true) . '",
        web_desc="' . $db->string_escape($web_desc, true) . '",
        web_keyword="' . $db->string_escape($web_keyword, true) . '"
        WHERE option_content ="' $bd->string_escape($option_id , true) . '" ';
$db->rq($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

does blur kill and give error for bad SQL statements?

I like to use

```
or die("Cannot Update: ".mysql_error());
```

It normally helps pinpoint the issue.